# WSo2 XSLT Parser Issue

Tags: wso2

WSO2 XSLT mediator  Parsing Issue in the below line

```
<xsl:template match="Id[some $sib in preceding-sibling::Id satisfies deep-equal(., $sib)]"/>
```

We have two servers in one server there is no issue and the transformation has happened successfully without node-set().   In the another WSO2 server there is an parser Issue. Unable to pase $ expected ] and it is asking for a node-set() in XSLT. 
   I have compared the conf files and repository files between the two servers and both are same. Even dropins and lib files are also same. We are just confused to sort out the issue since it is asking for node-set() in one server and in another server it is throwing exception because of node-set(). Kindly help on it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to copy the working instance from one server to another server and then try testing.
If that is not possible then can you confirm whether other XSLT's are working fine or not.

Comment: Whichever XSLT we are calling via WSO2 XSLT mediator whereever I use $ symbol [other than while using variable] we are experiancing the parser issue in one instance without nodeset and other instance works fine without nodeset. It is not restricted to this paticular XSLT.

Comment: In this case i believe that there must me some extra characters added in some of the configuration file which is causing this issue, you need to revisit all the configuration files again and check them, however if still you face issue i would recommend to copy the working instance into new server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  the issue has been solved. Since we were using Linux environment it was taking the Saxon processor by default where as in Windows wso2 takes the xalon processor to process the xslt. So in linux we have pointed  manually in the wso2server.sh file to manually point to xalon processor and it is working fine. Thanks..,

Comment: Good that the issue is resolved however you never mentioned that wso2  instance are running on different OS , in your case it was linux and windows